# Div doesnt have any height

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am constructing a div on the fly using Jquery, and appending it to the body or any element. 
after appending, when i try to get get the height it gives 0. In Chrome i checked all its height property its 0. what could be the problem.

This is my code to append :

```
 var template = '<div class="capMainSection"> 
       <div class="CAP"> </div>
       <div class="scrolldiv repeatSection" style="display:none;""> 
         <div class="header sectionheader"> </div> 
           <div class="content"> 
               <div class="leftColumn"> 
                   <div class="show" id="capInfo"> 
                     <div class="label1">CA Contacts:</div> 
                     <div class="label2"><p>CA Lead:<span class="LeadName"></span><span class="LeadEmail"></span></p></div> 
                     <div class="lable3"><p>Lead:<span class="vLeadName"></span><span class="vLeadEmail"></span></p></div>   

                   </div> 
                   <div class="hidden" id="facInfo"> 
                     <div class="label1"><span class="facid"></span><span class="facName"></span></div> 
                     <div class="label2"><span class="city"></span><span class="state"></span><span
 class="country"></span></div> 
                   </div>              </div>
               <div class="rightColumn"> 
                   <div class="rightGroup"> 
                     <div class="groupproto"> 
                       <p><span class="protocolname show"></span>
                       <span class="date_class show"></span></p>
                     </div>
                     <div class="statusClass hidden"></div>
                     <div class="approvedFinding show"></div>
                     <div class="closedFinding show"></div>
                     <div class="verifiedFinding show"></div>
                     <div class="lasActivity show"></div>
                   </div> 
                     <div class="linkButton"> 
                           <input type="button" class="lplinkbutton" value="&gt;">
                     </div> 
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
     </div>';
```

i am cloning the div first then appending

```
templateNode = $('.repeatSection').clone(true);
//change the display none to show
$(templateNode).find('.content').attr('id',capRow);
$('.capMainSection').append($(templateNode));
```

css

```
.content {
clear: both;
font-size: 13px;
}

.leftColumn {
float: left;
width: 40%;
padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;
}

.rightColumn {
float: right;
width: 50%;
padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it floated by any chance ?

Comment: Edit your ques properly and make a fiddle

Comment: some content inside are floated

Comment: if they float or have absolute position, they won't have a height.

Comment: just FYI `clone()` returns a jquery object. you don't need to wrap `templateNode` with jquery each time.

Comment: i have posted CSS as well, there are no position absolute

Comment: actually, i have link in that, and i want its height to be the height of class "content". but content itself deosnt have any height. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.capMainSection {overflow: hidden;}
```

Or, you can do this:

```
.capMainSection:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: @SharathBangera Do you have a fiddle dude?